# Strictly Increasing Sequences of Length n in a List

Tags: list-manipulation

I need to determine how many strictly increasing sequences of a certain length (e.g. 5) are contained in a list of integers. I would be very happy if someone could help me. A sequence would be considered strictly increasing if a<b<c.

```
list=BlockRandom[RandomInteger[11,{11111}],RandomSeeding->1234];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
length = 5;

Count[And @@@ Positive[Partition[Differences[list], length-1, 1]], True]
```

> ```
> 42
> ```

You can also use:

```
Count[Positive[Partition[Differences[list], length-1, 1]], {True ..}]

Count[Partition[Unitize @ Ramp @ Differences[list], length-1, 1], {1 ..}]

Count[Subsequences[Unitize @ Ramp @ Differences[list], {length-1}], {1 ..}]

Total[Times @@@ Subsequences[Unitize @ Ramp @ Differences @ list, {length-1}]]

Total @ BlockMap[Apply[Times], Unitize @ Ramp @ Differences @ list, length-1, 1]

Count[Less @@@ Partition[list, length, 1], True]

Count[Subsequences[list, {length}], _?(Apply[Less])]

Count[BlockMap[Apply[Less], list, length, 1], True]

Total @ Boole[Less @@@ Subsequences[list, {length}]]

Total @ Boole[BlockMap[Apply[Less], list, length, 1]]

Length @ Select[Partition[list, length, 1], Apply[Less]]

Total[Boole[Less @@@ Partition[list, length, 1]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
length = 5;

Length @ SequenceCases[list, {p : Repeated[_, {length}]} /; 
    Apply[Less] @ {p}, Overlaps -> True]
```